# simulate click on link in html

Tags: .net, vb.net

Could someone please take a look at his link; its safe but if not comfortable just look at next paragraph.
http://blog.isao.net/

When you look at the source page there is a link at the src tag

```
<frame src="http://track-back.net/Top.blog?userType=1" name="main">
```

How would I activate this link from vb.net since when you click on it all the html content appears and when I use the webbrowser control to navigate to it, I get the same original html. Any ideas deeply appreciated. I also tried using

```
web1.Document.InvokeScript(url)
```

but this just does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
HtmlElementCollection elements = web1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("main");

foreach(HtmlElement ele in elements)
{
    ele.Invoke("Click");
}
```

Please note, the code above is just a helper to get you on your way. The `foreach` clicking on each iteration is quite silly at the end of the day, so tweak this to your own needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Before I change my code to implement the webbrowser control, just wanted to know if this can incorporated into the httpwebrequest control that I use to fetch url and html content.